# How to parse data-extension attribute with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to parse an HTML file, but I'm unable to parse the "data-extension" attribute of an "a" tag.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="/websitenews.html" class="video" data-extension='{"mediaObj":{"url":"http://a-website.com/ondemand/226/217.js","offset":"0.0"}}' title="Video start">
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
foreach($html->find('a[class=video]') as $e) {
  echo $e->data-extension;
}
```

But all it is echoing is a series of zeros.  How can I echo the url within the data-extension, i.e., "http://a-website.com/ondemand/226/217.js" ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
foreach($html->find('a[class=video]') as $e)
{
  $json = json_decode($e->{'data-extension'});
  foreach($json as $key=>$data)
  {
    echo $data->url;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah what he said